# Java Generics questions for multiple type parameters

Tags: java, generics

I have this code:

```
public interface IDimension<S extends IDimension<S,T>, T extends Number> extends Comparable<S> {
  T toNumber();

  default T toBaseNumber() {
    return toNumber();
  }

  S fromNumber( T units );

  Class<T> numberType();
}
```

When I implement `IDimension` like below(`Implementation1`), I get `'Type parameter 'TestBaseSample' is not within its bound; should implement 'IDimension<TestBaseSample<Float,Integer>, java.lang.Long>'` error:

Implementation1 :

```
class TestBaseSample<Integer, Float> 
    implements IDimension<TestBaseSample<Float, Integer>, Long> { 
}
```

I understand why 'Implementation1' gives error, but not able to understand why 'Implementation2' and 'Implementation3' works?

Implementation2:

```
class TestBaseSample2<Integer, Float> 
    implements IDimension<TestBaseSample2<Float, Float>, Long> {
}
```

Implementation3 :

```
class TestBaseSample3<Integer, Float> 
    implements IDimension<TestBaseSample3<Integer, Integer>, Long> {
}
```

Comment: Do you realize that you are making Integer and Float into variable type names? eg. `class TestBaseSample3<T, S>` where T and S are generic types. http://ideone.com/Zq4AVt for example. Maybe you should change those to T &  S so it is clear, or make them concrete. `class TestBaseSample3 implements ...`

Comment: @matt you should turn this into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are attempting to create a concrete type, but you are actually creating generic parameters and giving them the names of java classes.

Consider your first example `TestBaseSample2` if we change the generic parameters to T and S

```
class TestBaseSample2<T, S> 
    implements IDimension<TestBaseSample2<S, S>, Long> {
}
```

Now, you should be able to make an instance provided `S` is a Long and `T` can be anything else.

Here is a simpler example.

```
static class OtherList<Integer> extends ArrayList<Integer>{}

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    OtherList<String> list = new OtherList<>();
    list.add("this");
    System.out.println(list.size());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove all types from your implementations (and never name generic parameters using class names, *especially* classes from the JDK - use single letters):

```
class TestBaseSample implements IDimension<TestBaseSample, Long> { 
}

class TestBaseSample2 implements IDimension<TestBaseSample2, Long> {
}

class TestBaseSample3 implements IDimension<TestBaseSample3, Long> {
}
```